Android Application With AWS authntication
I am developing an Native android application to detect plant disease using Deep learning, in which i have choose AWS as back-end support provider, as I am a beginner and I do not have much knowledge about back-end , i am just getting started.
So till yet i have success fully integrated AWS amplify with android studio , I have created the UI for my Application as well , In AWS i have created IAM role , user pool , and identity pool.
I want to to a phone number and otp based authentication for my application can anyone help me with a guided roadmap , how can i achieve a phone number and otp based authentication machenism to do a Succesfully  SignUp SignIn Process.
Please help be with it , A step by step guide would be really helpfull.
Thank you in advance.
I have tried to add a class called MyAmplify.java , and after that i have written the code for SignUpActivity.java.
It is creating new entry in AWS cognito user pool , but otp is not coming to the phone number.
I am expecting a step by step roadmap to achieve a successful SignUp SignIn process using AWS Cognito based on phone number and otp method.

This question is way too broad for stackoverflow. Please check the [tour] and [ask].
